# typeahead bootstrap, trigger when an item is selected or focused from the menu and get a value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, autocomplete, callback, twitter-bootstrap

By using typeahead bootstrap I would like to trigger when an item is selected or focused from the menu in order to
set a particular value related to the selected value.

Please see the comments on the code to understand exactly what I mean.

```
element.typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    source: function () {
        // users is a Backbone.Collection
        users = _.map(users, function(user) {
            return user.get('first_name')+' '+user.get('last_name');
        });

        return users;

    }
}).change(function (event) {
        // this function which is called when the user set a value 
        // should be able to get the user.get('id') of the selected user
        // any idea how to make it?
});
```

Answer (score 4):

This might be useful for you. I use an extension to Typeahead that allows you to call remote data sources. It comes with an `onselect()` callback function where you could do what you want.

[typeahead extension GIST](https://gist.github.com/1866577)

Here is some sample code:

```
    initialization: function() {
        this.user = new User();
        // Or fetch the user so it has an id, etc.
    },
    initTypeahead: function() {
        var self = this;
        var element = this.$('#input');

        element.typeahead({
            source: userCollection.toJSON(),
            property: 'name',
            onselect: function(userObj) {  // This is the line to pay attention to
                var userModel = userCollection.get(userObj.id);
                // Do something with the userModel
            }
        });
    }
```

So basically in my code, when I query my DB I get back a JSON that sets the value of each selection to whatever data I passed back from my ajax.

With the `onselect(obj)` I'm passing the obj into my callback and I happen to just attach it as data to the input element. But you could easily add your own custom code that utilizes the user data (user.id) you already have and do whatever it is you do along with the value you threw into your selection. Meaning, user.id should be available in your `onselect()` callback as long as it's in the proper scope of things.

Comment: +1 Thanks for you reply. Actually obj parameter of onselect is the value selected by the user. To me it's not clear yet how should I pass the user model to `onselect function`.

Comment: Right. The point I guess is depending on the scope of your user variable, you could just stick it in there. `self.user.id` in the callback. For example, maybe in your View you have this.user = new User(); Then in the onselect callback you just use something like self.user.id Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question. Is the user a selection value? Or you just want to use the user.id in your callback manipulation?

Comment: The point is: each `item` corresponds to a different `user model`. When I select the item I need to access that specific `user model`. The scope of the view is the `user collection`. One solution could be to get the `user.id` from the `user.first_name + user.last_name` but to me it seems quite laborious and I would like to find a better solution.

Comment: In that case maybe focus on the `source` option. Source can be a function (that makes an ajax call to server and gets back json array) or simply an array already available like [{id:1,name:'Smith'},{id:2, name:'Mandy'}]. So maybe something like `source: userCollection.toJSON()` is what you want. Now your obj arg in the `onselect()` represents the JSON data of each user. You could basically use that to select the correct model from your collection. `userModel = userCollection.get(obj.id)` I'll edit the example for simplicity.